# Get Id of the newly created record in Apex

Tags: apex, soql, class, map, list

I have the following Apex method:

```
public static void createJourney(Id accountId) {
        
         // Step 1: get account record type
        Account accRecTypeName = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
        
        if(accRecTypeName.RecordType?.DeveloperName == 'Patient_Account') {
            
            // Step 2: Create a new Patient Journey record
            List<Patient_Journey__c> patientJourney = new List<Patient_Journey__c>();
            
            patientJourney.add(
                new Patient_Journey__c(
                    Name = 'Test Patient Journey',
                    Patient__c = accRecTypeName.Id,
                    Status__c = 'Active'
                )
            );
            
            insert patientJourney;
            
            // Get ID of the newly inserted Patient Journey record
            for(Patient_Journey__c getPJID : patientJourney) {
                patientJourneyID = getPJID.Id; // Line 25
            }
          
            // Step 3: Read records from custom metadata type 'Journey Step'
            Map<String, Journey_Step__mdt> journeyStepMD = Journey_Step__mdt.getAll();
            List<Patient_Journey_Step__c> patientJourneySteps = new List<Patient_Journey_Step__c>();

            for (String getJSteps : journeyStepMD.keySet()) {
                
                // Step 4: Create a new Patient Journey Step records based on 'Journey Step'
                patientJourneySteps.add(
                    new Patient_Journey_Step__c(
                        Step_Name__c = journeyStepMD.get(getJSteps).Step_Name__c,
                        Order__c = journeyStepMD.get(getJSteps).Order__c,
                        Journey__c = patientJourneyID // Line 39
                    )
                );
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to get the Id of the newly created 'Patient_Journey__c' record. I get the following errors when saving the file:

- Line 25: Variable does not exist: patientJourneyID
- Line 39: Variable does not exist: patientJourneyID

Comment: Any specific reason to use list when inserting a single record?

Comment: I am new to Apex and don't have a good understanding of when to use and not to use List. This is how I do normally

Answer (score 2):

Let's simplify this code a bit

```
// Step 1: get account record type
Account accRecTypeName = [SELECT Id, RecordType.DeveloperName FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];
    
if(accRecTypeName.RecordType?.DeveloperName != 'Patient_Account') {return;}

        
// Step 2: Create a new Patient Journey record
Patient_Journey__c> patientJourney = new Patient_Journey__c(
                Name = 'Test Patient Journey',
                Patient__c = accRecTypeName.Id,
                Status__c = 'Active'
            );
        );
        
insert patientJourney;
        
      
// Step 3: Read records from custom metadata type 'Journey Step'
Map<String, Journey_Step__mdt> journeyStepsByName = Journey_Step__mdt.getAll();
List<Patient_Journey_Step__c> patientJourneySteps = new List<Patient_Journey_Step__c>();

for (String jStepName : journeyStepsByName.keySet()) {
            
  // Step 4: Create a new Patient Journey Step records based on 'Journey Step'
  patientJourneySteps.add(
          new Patient_Journey_Step__c(
              Step_Name__c = journeyStepMD.get(jStepName).Step_Name__c,
              Order__c = journeyStepMD.get(jStepName).Order__c,
              Journey__c = patientJourney.Id 
                )
            );
}
insert patientJourneySteps;
```

*Pro tip -- list/set variables should be named as plurals - e.g. `patientJourneys`; maps should be named thingsBykey e.g. `journeySytepsByName`; for loop iteration variable should be named to align with its type; e.g. `pj` instead of `getPJId`. Good variable names make debugging easier*

Answer (score 1):

You need to instantiate the `patientJourneyID` as string or id like this.

```
Id patientJourneyID;
// Get ID of the newly inserted Patient Journey record
   for(Patient_Journey__c getPJID : patientJourney) {
       patientJourneyID = getPJID.Id; // Line 25
   }
```

Comment: I did this but it still shows me error in line 39.

Comment: Id would need to declared outside of the loop for having a proper scoping

Comment: you are right, updated the answer